# Microsoft edge tabs detached from main window when clicked

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, chromium, microsoft-edge

I know dragging the tab bar downward will result in creating new windows for the tab
But this happens even if you just click it. This is so weird behavior that no other chromium browsers report. I swear to god I've never dragged it even slightly when this bug happened, multiple times.

Quite annoying having to reattach the tab back into the main window everytime it moves away.

Answer (score 0):

> I know (1) dragging the tab bar downward will result in creating new
> windows for the tab (2) But this happens even if you just click it.

**(1) Yes** - default behavior.

**(2) No** - not here, several machines, should not happen

Things to try:

**(A) Repair Edge:**   Settings, Apps, Installed Apps (Apps and Features), scroll down to Microsoft Edge, 3 dots (...), Modify and the Repair. Restart computer.

**(B) DISM and SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

This should help get Edge working correctly.